# What to do with plain wrong questions

Tags: discussion

Stumbling upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24211140/reduce-blank-space-between-bar-button-items-in-uinavigationbar/24211387#24211387) got me thinking.

What should I do with questions that are just plain wrong?

For example, that question completely goes against the Apples Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: duplicate of: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/186381)

Comment: Um... what? How is it a duplicate of that?

Comment: Did you read through the question?  You've posted an example of an XY problem; someone asking how to implement a mechanism instead of describing a problem, to which there is a better mechanism that should be used to solve that problem.

Comment: See also [Is "don't do it" a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891)

Comment: @Servy I broadly read through it, but not thoroughly since it expected it to be a duplicate...

Comment: SO is littered with *"should I cut off my arm using a hacksaw or a powersaw?"* questions

Comment: @Plutonix Which is of course entirely understandable.  Some people just don't know why cutting off your own arm just because it iches might not be the best way of dealing with a mosquito bite.  The real problem is [the people that answer those questions as asked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260500/1159478).

Comment: Hm. I would flag to close as a dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891 ("Is 'don't do it' a valid answer?") - but apparently you can't close a meta.SO as a dup of a meta.SE :p

Comment: Goes against Apple guidelines?  Sic an NDA on his ass?

Comment: Related but _not_ a duplicate: [Close reason for "not in my universe" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258731)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're up to it, you can try to figure out what the OP's actual business requirement and give them a solution that fulfills that requirement.

Even if what you post is not an answer by the letter of the question, it's okay so long as it's an answer by the spirit of the question.

---

If you don't think that it's worth it to try and find out the actual requirement, than you can always just move on, and vote/comment as you please.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a technical solution to the programming problem, provide it, and add a caution about the fact that it's a terrible idea, with your reasoning.

If there's really no feasible way to achieve the desired result, then provide that information, with justification/background details, as an answer.

> What you're trying to do is disallowed by your vendor's rules

is a real concern that the asker should be made aware of, but it doesn't constitute a  good Stack Overflow answer; questions that are solely about App Store guidelines and the like are off-topic, and so are answers.