# If another question is the answer, is it a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The question [Why split the `<script>` tag when writing it with `document.write()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write) takes a solution and asks what problem is is solving.

The question [Script tag in JavaScript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659749/script-tag-in-javascript-string) takes that problem and looks for a solution.

The latter has been marked as a duplicate of the former, despite the fact that they are asking the opposite thing. It is, however, possible to infer the answer to the former from the latter.

Are they still duplicates?

---

Now if we take a step back and look at [Want to load javascript only on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917796/want-to-load-javascript-only-on-mobile-devices).

This question is focused on the broader picture and doesn't show that the OP has identified that the `</script>` is the cause of the problem. The second question is a closer duplicate of the third than the first.

Should the third be marked as a duplicate of either of them?

Comment: Does reading the content correctly answer the question?  If yes, close it, if no, leave it open.

Comment: That's all very well to say, but in general, "Reading the content correctly" may be beyond the capabilities of a beginner if the target question of the duplicate flag is written using advanced terminology or refers to advanced concepts. That's normally not an issue with duplicates because if one answer is too technical, a simpler answer can be provided - but not in this case because you can't write another *question* on the same page.

Answer (score 9):

OK to be duplicate.

Duplicate serves two purposes:

- points to an existing answer to the given question (should be *close enough* for regular programmer to understand)
- improve search by keeping alternative interpretations of the question for search purposes but linking to "canonical" answer.

The current duplicate thread (as combination of question and answer) definitely provides an answer for original question. Are there better duplicates - most likely, but unless you know real canonical answer it is not really worth spending a lot of time searching for *slightly* better one.

Answer (score 8):

I see the two questions as different. One is:

> Why is x done?

with an answer of:

> To solve y problem

The other is:

> How do I solve y problem?

the answer of course is:

> Do x

Someone searching for "Why is x done?" isn't going to find the "How do I solve y problem?" question, and the answers won't be geared toward the question being asked.

Someone searching for "How do I solve y problem?" isn't going to find "Why is x done?", and again, the answers won't be geared toward the question being asked.

Are they related? Absolutely. Should they be linked? very likely. Are they *exact* duplicates? **No**.

Comment: The whole purpose of "close as duplicate" is to solve the searchability issue.  The action is, after all, *close* and not *delete*.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258771/103167

Comment: the answer to y problem could also be z and the x could also be done to solve a, as well