# Questions about Dennis Ritchies's opinion

Tags: support, opinion-based

I'm wondering about correct boundary between historical questions and primarily opinion-based ones.

Here's an example: [What was the original reason for [blah]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244028/fnord), which quite clearly asks for the original reason, not your opinion about whether [blah] is a good thing, or should have been done differently. As I read it, the goal of the question is to get [this kind of informative, unopinionated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250270/fnord). However, I'm not surprised that the question attracted an answer "almost entirely based on opinions" before it was closed. Questions about Dennis Ritchie's motivation when he made some design choice in Unix in 1975 do attract information-free answers about whether that design choice was right or wrong.

The "primarily opinion-based" close reason suggests to me that this question ought to be closed, even though the good answer is good and answers something I've been curious about. The question will attract opinion-based answers, so close it. The close reason's phrasing doesn't mention whether the question will receive (or has received) a factual, unopinionated answer.

It seems to me that reviewers handle this grey area a little haphazardly.

Could we have some guidance on how to handle questions that are about historical record, but are likely to be answered with irrelevant opinion?

Comment: Related: [Are language specs and their developments on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306471/are-language-specs-and-their-developments-on-topic)

Comment: For one, [retrocomputing.se] seems to welcome questions that are about such historic records. For Stack Overflow, a question has to be _a __practical__, answerable problem that is unique to software development_ ([help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), and this question doesn't seem to be very practical, it seems purely theoretical to me. We don't have a pre-defined off-topic/not practical close reason, so people make due with what's closest in applicability.

Comment: The ones I've can think of as I type _directly involve programming or programming tools_ and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentions that phrase as a reason for being on-topic. But moving to retrocomputing would work for some; thanks.

Comment: IIRC from previous discussions (which I can't find currently), the idea is that such questions are "primarily opinion-based" because of how small the chance is that the few people who can answer such a question, will actually answer it. But not everyone agrees with that either, it's a bit of a grey area as you wrote.

Comment: Hmya, the meta question does a good job by itself explaining why.  Not unlike how all major astronomy discoveries end up getting attributed to the Hubble telescope.  Far from the truth.  Dennis actually did a fairly decent job documenting what he did, the same cannot be said for the many other AT&T engineers.  These people are all long retired or pushing up the daisies, there is no reliable primary source for how it all happened left.

Comment: @HansPassant There are people around who have old documentation and can cite it. I myself have dead flat trees from before the web and have used it to answer questions, and I've seen an SO answer that quoted one of the unix greats via an interview.

Comment: @arnt It's an AND condition, just being about programming or programming tools isn't enough, it also has to be a practical, answerable problem unique to software development too.