# Where is the "opinion-based" line drawn with failed audits?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24840956) over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980110/example-of-stream-reduction-with-distinct-combiner-and-accumulator). I said it was unsalvageable as primarily opinion-based. The review system said I failed because the question "looks OK". The question is asking "I'm not interested in trivial examples, but natural examples that I can encounter in practice while doing reduction on parallel streams."

The asker has no problem to solve. There is not an underlying task to complete, or hurdle to overcome. This is in essence asking the API authors to justify the existence of some piece of functionality. Maybe they'll chime in, maybe other people have found this API useful, maybe there are concrete examples that can be provided. But this will all be opinion ("we created this API because ...", "we found it useful because ...", "I think it's not trivial because ..."). In my understanding of Stack Overflow's purpose, this question is outside of it. I don't know if there is a Stack Exchange site where this question would belong (maybe software engineering?) but it doesn't seem to fit here.

Does the question fit the definition of "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: :shrug: doesn't seem anywhere near as blatantly off topic of other similar examples of "why was x built this way", to me it sounds more like a case of "is there any situation where x is true", and the answer provides a few, thus effectively answering the question. It's not too broad either, because just one example would be enough to "solve" it. I personally would have skipped that review.

Comment: The line is drawn by an SQL query, and the query draws its data from people's actions, so it won't be any more coherent than people are. If five randomly chosen SOers think one question is okay and five others think another, similar question isn't (and some other conditions) those questions may both be used for audits, with opposing "correct" responses. You may find some of the comments on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376536/fnord) interesting, even if the question isn't relevant.

Comment: It is an audit, not a review.  Once in a while they pick one that has a lot of helpful votes, easy to pass when the reviewer takes care of double-checking why a flag from a concerned SO user needs to be dismissed.  You have to look, like the audit message says.  SO users don't have much a problem passing this particular audit, 8 out of 10 succeeded.  It wasn't supposed to be hard.  And of course it isn't, if you look.

Comment: What am I looking for, if not the content of the question?

Comment: Audits are supposed to be *obvious*. This one wasn't. As such, it was a bad audit. What Hans means, however, is that you can easily pass the audit anyway by clicking through to the post, seeing that it was well-received, and thus indicate that it "Looks OK". This will pass the audit, and counts as "paying attention". The audits are designed to catch robo-reviewers. If you click through to investigate, you aren't robo-reviewing. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug