# How can I deal with questions in which the user asks something unknown?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting

Today I asked this question: *[Generate a random number that guarantees a mean different from the average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988738/generate-a-random-number-that-does-guarantees-a-mean-different-to-the-average)*

It clearly seems that I didn't know how randomness worked as someone stated in one comment. At that point everything was fine, but then I started getting downvotes because of that. (There were four downvotes in less than one minute.)

So, is it right to downvote a question when the user doesn't even know anything about his own question?

I think the question was clearly asked, and that is what should be taken into account when voting up/down, isn't it?

How should these questions be handled?

Comment: closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258731/103167

Comment: People generally downvote based on whether they think a question is useful or not. It's great that asking the question made you learn something about probability theory! But that doesn't mean that other people have to agree that it's a useful question, and if they don't then they can downvote it. A question being "clear" is only one of the three downvote reasons you can see when hovering over the downvote button.

Comment: I suspect the reason why [Niet posted what he did as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988738/generate-a-random-number-that-guarantees-a-mean-different-from-the-average#comment76952283_44988738) is because it's still possible to answer your question. The issue is just with your use of the term "random". From your description, it's clear that you *don't* actually want a random number, and Niet is pointing that out. It still remains for someone to post an *arbitrary* number generation algorithm that satisfies your requirements. (As for the meta issue, don't obsess over downvotes!)

Comment: That comment is completely wrong. This is not an issue about randomness but an issue of uniformity. Randomness doesn't require uniformity.